# Javascript save value on every button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi what I'm trying to achieve is to attack other user and minimize his health. What happens now is that everytime I click button the user hp on every click starts minimize from 100. Let's say on first click I hit him with 70 and now it's shows that he has 30. But On next click again he have 100 hp and again hit happens with some damage. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines

```
var attackerHealth = 100;
var userHealth = 100;
```

set the health values to 100 every time the function is executed. You will need to track the health outside of this function if you want the reduced health to be tracked over multiple attacks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var attackerHealth = 100;
var userHealth = 100;
```

With those variables inside the click-handler you say the attacker has at every click full HP again. Try to define your variables outside of this function.

EDIT: i'm just too slow in answering :-/

Comment: Thanks and for you!